# how do you do system call interrupts in C?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I learned from [download.savannah.gnu.org/.../ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf)
that programs interrupt the kernel, and that is how things are done. What I want to know is how you do that in C (if it's possible)

Comment: Might be interesting -- http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/tlk-toc.html -- also, note that most drivers *are* written in C (*with* support of kernel functions in kernel-space). There may be some support to transfer to user-space, I don't know.

Comment: In Soviet Russia, user program interrupts kernel!  <rim shot>  Thank you, I'll be here all week!

Comment: You don't actually interrupt the kernel, because it is not running - your user code is. (Assuming local CPU view.)

Comment: ^ The x86 "int" instruction is quite misnamed; other architectures have it properly named as "trap".

Answer (score 4):

There is no platform-independent way (obviously)!  On x86 platforms, system-calls are typically implemented by placing the system-call code in the `eax` register, and triggering `int 80h` in assembler, which causes a switch to kernel-mode.  The kernel then executes the relevant code based on what it sees in `eax`.

Answer (score 3):

User processes usually request kernel services by calling [system call](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) wrapper functions from [Standard C Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libc). You can do it manually with [`syscall(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscall.2.html).

Answer (score 1):

The user program's interaction with the kernel is going to be very platform-specific, so it usually happens behind the scenes in the various library routines.  So  one just calls `printf`, `write`, `select`, or other library routines, which allow the programmer to write code without worrying about the details of the kernel interface, device drivers, and so forth.

And the way it usually works is that when one of those library routines needs the kernel to do something on its behalf, it performs a low-level system call that *yields* its control of the CPU to the kernel.  It's the user program, not the kernel, that is the one being interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using glibc (which you probably are if you are using gcc and linux) then there is a syscall function in unistd.h that you can use.   It has different implementations for different architectures and operating systems, but the implementation is done in assembly (could be inline assembly).  `syscall` has a man page, so:

```
 man syscall
```

will give you some info.

If you are just curious about how all of this works then you should know that this has changed in Linux on x86 in recent years.  Originally interrupt 0x80 was used by Linux as the normal system call entry point on x86.  This worked well enough, but as processors got more advanced pipelining (starting an instruction before previous instructions have completed) interrupts have slowed down (relative to execution of regular code which has sped up, though some tests have shown that it has slowed down more than that).  The reason for this is that even when the `int` instruction is used to trigger an interrupt it works mostly the same as hardware triggered interrupts, which occur unpredictably, which causes them not to play nice with the pipelining of instructions (pipelining works better when code paths are predictable).

To help with this newer x86 processors have instructions specifically intended for making system calls, but Intel and AMD use different instructions for this (`sysenter` and `syscall`, respectively).  Additionally the Intel `systenter` instruction clobbers a general purpose register that Linux has used on x86_32 to pass a parameter to the kernel.  This means that programs have to know which of 3 possible system call mechanisms to use as well as possibly different ways of passing arguments to the kernel.  To get around all of this newer kernels map a special page of memory into programs (this page is called vsyscall and if you `cat /proc/self/maps` you will see an entry for it) that contains code for the system call mechanism that the kernel has determined should be used on the system, and newer versions of glib can implement their system call entry using the code in this page.

The point of all of this is that this isn't as simple as it used to be, but if you are just playing around on an x86_32 then you should be able to use the `int 80h` instruction because that will be supported on systems that can use one of the other mechanisms for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you don't really do it directly, but you'll end up doing this indirectly any time you use library functions that end up invoking system calls. File access, network access, etc, are typical examples of this.

Those functions will all end up "trapping" to the kernel, which will handle the request.